# Overloading the built-in type constructor in PHP

Tags: php, types, constructor, overloading

I'm trying to have it so, for every single Integer created, some text is outputted. For this, I'm looking to overload (or extend) the default Integer type.

I would like to have a built-in type (Integer, Array, String) to have a custom constructor like

```
public function __construct($data) { print $data; }
```

Is this possible? I can't find it ever even attempted before online.

Edit:

I have tried this:

```
class Integer { /*...*/ }
```

And this:

```
class Integer extends Integer { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: The default integer and string types are no objects in PHP. Thus no overloading. What makes you think they are?

Comment: Nothing necessarily makes me think they are Objects, it's just easier to explain what I want when I think of them as Objects in that what I want to do to them, I could do to an Object.

Comment: Well you can write wrappers around them and use those instead of using the native integer and string types but is that really necessary? Loss of performance is just one downside of this.

Comment: I don't mind performance hits, because it'll just be to help me debug. The problem with custom classes or wrappers is that '$x=5' would not make one of my classes, it would still make an integer, so the constructor would not be fired. It needs to work with constant values/strings, too, created as you normally would create an int.

Comment: That is not possible. As I said they are no objects in PHP itself so you can not extend and overload them. What you want is the best of both worlds: access natively and expect it to be your custom class. Even if they were objects that would not be possible, because you would have to create a new MyInteger(5) instance to actually work with your own code.

Comment: If built in types WERE objects, wouldn't I just be able to extend it with itself? 'class myGuy extends myGuy { /* new methods*/ }'

Comment: Then you would be redeclaring a class. You can only have one class with the same name at runtime or you will get a fatal error. Have you even tried that out?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that out, actually. So there's no way to edit a class once it's defined?

Comment: Of course, you can extend it, but it will have to have another name to distinguish the two classes from each other. So what you describe is not possible. And as I said before, PHP just doesn't use objects for strings and integers...

Comment: Ok. Do you know of ANY ways to have an action triggered when a int literal is stored in a variable? Any way at all to capture every variable definition that occurs?

Comment: No... You should use a debugger to debug ...

Comment: If your only reason to do this is to help you debug your scripts, you're going about debugging your scripts in the wrong way. People have been debugging PHP forever without overloading non-overloadable native types.

Comment: Yes, but regardless of the reason, I'm just curious if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP native scalar types are not objects, you cannot overload them.
You could write wrapper classes and use them like so:

```
$int = new Integer(5);
```

But that's probably much more work than makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it just doesn't have the functionality I wanted of calling the constructor just from doing this: $x=5;

Comment: Yeah, then PHP isn't the right language for you. :-P